# Excel Vba sheet protection issue

Tags: excel, vba

I have protected excel sheet with specific columns protected. I want to allow users to apply filters and format protected cells. Is it possible, if so,please suggest me a code

Comment: I've always liked Morse code.

Comment: @Jeeped lol, you'd need to add reference to the Morse Library.

Answer (score 0):

Allowing formatting in a protected worksheet is not a problem.

Allowing filtering is possible as well, but somehow limited. You cannot allow the users to enable or disable filtering themselves, you can only allow them to *use* an autofilter that you put in place prior to protecting the worksheet.

Consider this code:

```
Sub ProtectSheet3()
    Sheet3.Cells.AutoFilter
    Sheet3.Protect Password:="123", userInterfaceOnly:=True, _
        AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
End Sub
```

In this code, we enabled formatting cells, and we have setup an autofilter and allowed users to use it. If you don't setup the autofilter prior to protecting the worksheet, there's no way to say "I want to allow the users to start the filtering feature by themselves".

It works the same if you protect the worksheet by hand (instead of through VBA). first setup the filter and then select the options `Allow Formatting Cells` and `Allow Filtering` in the `Protect Sheet` dialog.